# How to check image version exists od not in carrierwave rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

Some pictures have mobile version or some have not. I want to check either mobile version existing or not

I used

```
image.mobile.file.exists?
```

But it also giving error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `mobile' for
```

How can I check that?

Comment: Can you show your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an image version called 'mobile' defined in your uploader.

If you've called your uploader ImageUploader, then open up app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb

Add the following version to the file:

```
  version :mobile do
    process resize_to_fill: [620, 270]
  end
```

Swap out the x and y sizes for whatever you need. After this all new images will have the 'mobile' attribute available. If you want it to apply to all old images, then you will need to save them and the new version will be available.

Comment: file.exists is  a very slow process

Comment: It executes an http request to validate the file exists so takes around half a second depending on your connection. Not a lot you can do about that.

Comment: I am checking from s3